# Sticky Navbar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I understand this seems to be a common request but after digging through several posts I can't find a solution and/or lack the knowledge to tailor the javascript to my needs.

I am looking for a way to have my Navbar stick to the top of the page once it reaches the top (scrolling far enough down). The issues I have is that my Navbar is currently positioned using flex, and not already at the top of the page.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrXKyY)

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {text-align: center;}
#logo2 img {
 margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
.menu2 {
 display: flex; /* displays children inline */
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 list-style-type: none;
 background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
}

li {
 flex: 1; /* each takes as much width as it can, i.e. 25% */
 border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}

li:last-child {
 border: none;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font: Verdana;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #EAE0D2;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 20px 0;
}

li a:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(#404040, #3E3E3E);
}

.active {
 background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}
```

```html
<header id="logo2">
 <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
</header>

<nav>
<ul id="navigation" class="menu2">
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="art.html">ART</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a bootstrap, Foundation or Another CSS framework?

Comment: I am not familiar with Bootstrap or Foundation. I will read more into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I eventually found an answer to my question. For those of you interested.

**JS**

```
var num = 240; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu2').addClass('fixed');
        $('.main').addClass('main2');
    } else {
        $('.menu2').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.main').removeClass('main2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu2 {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  position: sticky;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}

.emptySpace {width: 100%; height: 1000000px;}
```

```html
<span class="menu2">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
  <a href="">Link 4</a>
  <a href="">Link 5</a>
</span>

<!-- the div below is to allow you to scroll so you can see how it works (it's absolutely useless) -->
<div class="emptySpace"></div>
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use

HTML:

```
<span class="menu2">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.menu2 {position: sticky;}
```

This will cause the navigation bar to stick to the top of the screen as the user scrolls down.
You can read into this a bit more at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).
Also, check out my [Weave](https://liveweave.com/duslbf) at [LiveWeave](https://liveweave.com/).